# Visual Studio Web Performance Test - Dynamic Querystring Parameter from Hidden Field

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

We have an application that generates Quotes. In the early stages of the application a unique QuoteId is generated. This id can be found in a hidden field, that is sent to the client in an MVC Partial View (over an ajax request).

I need to be able to extract this hidden field, and then reuse the value in subsequent requests. I can see how to add dynamic query string parameters, but my attempts so far to extract the id have not worked.

So far I have been focusing on extraction rules on the previous request to try and get the data (I've tried extracting both Form Fields and Hidden Fields).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution - instead of trying to add a query string parameter what I really wanted to do was modify the URL based on the dynamic value.

I extracted a form field in the previous step, then modified the URL with the parameter so that it read:

```
{{WebServer}}/Controller/Method/{{QuoteId}}
```